# Loading different view port based on input parameter

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Currently, we use an embedded tomcat, to start up ext-js application locally.

The Ext.application contains below code that loads the view port:

```
var viewPort = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
     layout  : 'fit',
        items: [
           Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {                    
                items: [
                    Ext.create('Tab 1', {title: ' Tab 1'}), 
                    Ext.create('Tab 2', {title: ' Tab 2'}),
                 ],

            }),
        ]
  });
```

Can I load the tab2, above in the panel on condition basis. How can I configure say an option, some where in the web-application that loads tab2 only if the option is set?

For better clarification, something like -

```
// load tab 1 
if (optionSet) {
 // then load tab 2
}
```

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See if this snippet helps you:

```
var items = [{
     xtype:'tab1'
    ,title:'Tab 1'
}];
if(condition) {
    items.push({
         xtype:'tab2'
        ,title:'Tab 2'
    });
}
var viewPort = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
     layout:'fit'
    ,items:[{
         xtype:'tabpanel'
        ,items:items
    }]
});
```